# Duplicate entity with one to many in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails

This is a somewhat newbie question.

I have a one to many relationship in rails, think Project with many Tasks.
I want to provide the user with the ability to recreate the Project and Tasks for a new Project (think onboarding an employee and then using the same tasks). So on each project record, add a `Duplicate`  button. When clicked I would create a new project with a few properties changed and recreate all the tasks for that project.

My question is general, what would I do and where? I know rails offers a *.dup function. Would that go in a model? Controller? What is the rails way to approach this.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This would be a good method in the `Project` class.

```
class Project
  has_many :tasks

  def duplicate
    p = Project.create(name: "Copy of #{ name }")

    tasks.each do |t|
      p.tasks.create(name: t.name)
    end

    p
  end
```

Then, to use it,

```
new_project = existing_project.duplicate
```

Answer (score 0):

What's about [deep_cloneable](https://github.com/moiristo/deep_cloneable)?

> The `deep_clone` method supports a couple options that can be specified by passing an options hash. Without options, the behaviour is the same as ActiveRecord's `dup` method.

```rb
project.deep_clone(include: :tasks)
```